# How to fix "Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated" error in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework, robotframework-ide

I keep on getting this error when running my Robot Framework script:

"Escaping empty cells with '\' before line continuation marker '...' is deprecated. Remove escaping before Robot Framework 3.2."

Here is a sample code:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Debug
    ${Str} =    Set Variable    Rose
    : FOR    ${Ctr}    IN RANGE    1    5
    \    Run Keyword If    '${Str}' == 'Test'    Log    Test
    \    ...    ELSE    Log    Not Test
```

I searched for a solution and I only got this link: https://gerrit.openbmc-project.xyz/#/c/openbmc/openbmc-test-automation/+/22245/

I can see that they used FOR/END instead of :FOR (which was working fine before).

```
FOR  ${userid}  IN RANGE  2  16
  ${user_info}=  Get User Info  ${userid}
  Run Keyword If  "${user_info['user_name']}" != ""
  ...  Run IPMI Standard Command  user set name ${userid} ""
END
```

However, when I try to change my code to use FOR/END, RIDE automatically changes it back to :FOR.

I use RIDE heavily and would like to continue to do so I need it to work around this error. My RIDE is the latest one so upgrade won't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Robot will never change your tests. Are you using RIDE?

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes sorry that's what I meant RIDE was changing the code. I editted my question.

Comment: @R. Lecc  RIDE is being updated to not change the test file. So far it has not been released because I am not happy with the results. If you want to use the unfinished development code get https://github.com/HelioGuilherme66/RIDE/tree/update_robot_3.1.2.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax for the FOR-loop is changed. From the documentation:

> Not closing loops with END, escaping keywords inside loops with \, and
>   using :FOR instead of FOR are all going to be deprecated in Robot
>   Framework 3.2. Users are advised to switch to the new syntax as soon
>   as possible.

With your code I can still run the test, but the deprecation warning is shown. To remove the warning this worked for me in Eclipse:

```
Debug
${Str} =    Set Variable    Rose
:FOR    ${Ctr}    IN RANGE    1    5
\    Run Keyword If    '${Str}' == 'Test'    Log    Test
    ...    ELSE    Log    Not Test
```

When you remove the escape character in the ELSE line the warning is no longer shown. This is a workaround though, untill a new version of RIDE comes along I guess.